# Angular proxy config for multiple target url

Tags: angular, object, webpack, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy

I have a few endpoints like below.

- abcd/text/data
- xyz/text/data
- Pqr/text/data

I am trying to add these in proxy config file as fixing cors error.

For single url it is working fine but for all url it is not working. What should i add object key here? As text/data is common in all url.

Correction after David Gerschcovsky's response.

```
{

"/text/*" : {

     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "pathRewrite": {
        "^/text/^": ""
    }

      }

}
```

How to add multiple entries with same object keys in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some parameters, try something like this:

```
    {
     "/text/*" : {

       "target": "abc"
       "secure": true,
       "changeOrigin": true,
       "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But how to add next url xyz/text/data in proxy file. The thing is my proxy object key "/text/*" is common for all url.